# Python pulling email addresses out of a text file and placing into a dictionary

Tags: python, extract

I am trying to pull email addresses out of a text file and put them into a dictionary.  The following code allows me to print them out.  Note: I am pulling my answer out via characters rather than words which I think is a problem in in itself.  How do I pull out email addresses and then assign them to a dictionary?

```py
    fname = input("Enter file:")
    try:
        fhand = open(fname)
    except:
        print('File cannot be opened:')
        exit()
    counts = dict() 
    for line in fhand: 
         words = line.split
         if line.startswith('From:'):
             print(line[6:])
```

Comment: 1. `words = line.split` isn't doing anything and can be removed. 2. Dictionaries have keys and values. What will they be here? For example, the key might be the person's name and the value is the e-mail address.

Comment: Also, adding a small example would be helpful.

Comment: The Pythonic way to write that `try/except` block is `with open(fname) as fhand:`.

Comment: A sample of the text file on which you're working on would help us understand your query better. Thanks!

Comment: It seems you are processing mbox files. If that is the case, take a look at the standard library module [`mailbox`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mailbox.html). I guess the class [`mailbox.mbox`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mailbox.html#mbox) will make your life easier.

Comment: Thank you everyone.  The key would be the email address.  The value would be the number of times the address appears in the file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to count e-mail senders from a mbox file format. If that is the case here is a solution using standard library modules from Python 3:

```py
from collections import Counter
# just to have a pretty output
from pprint import pprint
import mailbox

fname = input("Enter file:")

with mailbox.mbox(fname) as mbox:
    senders = Counter(msg['From'] for msg in mbox)
    pprint(senders)
```

As a good side effect of using `collections.Counter`, you can have something like this:

```py
print('Top 10 senders')
pprint(senders.most_common(10))
```

I hope it helps.